# Custom filters for Twig in Silex

Tags: twig, silex, twig-filter

I need to add custom filter for Twig in Silex framework. For example, I want apply this function to some variable:

```
public function addExclamation($text) {
    return $text.'!!!';
}
```

And in twig-template do something like this:

```
{{ text|exclam }}
```

After reading http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html I create "Project_Twig_Extension.php":

```
class Project_Twig_Extension extends Twig_Extension
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'project';
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new Twig_SimpleFilter('exclam', 'addExclamation'),
        );
    }

    public function addExclamation($text) {
        return $text.'!!!';
    }
}
```

But I can't undersand where I need to put this file and how I can register this filter in "index.php" of Silex.

Can you give me step-by-step guide? Method, described at [Twig addFilter using Silex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9504309/twig-addfilter-using-silex) don't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "don't work"? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I create `InsolisExtension.php` and put it to `W:\home\example.com\Insolis\Twig`, after that I write in `index.php` registering code. Error: `Fatal error: Class 'Insolis\Twig\InsolisExtension' not found in W:\home\example.com\index.php` on line 39. Folder `vendor` is on the same level as the `index.php`.

Comment: You forgot to register the Insolis namespace in your autoloader.

Comment: I write `require_once __DIR__.'/App/Twig/AppExtension.php';` in "index.php" and it works! But I think that this is not quite right... How correctly register the namespace?

Comment: Read up on how composer works and how you can register your own namespaces in the autoloader.

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom filters like this:

```
$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function(\Twig_Environment $twig) {
    $twig->addFilter(new Twig_SimpleFilter('exclaim', function ($value) {
        return $value.'!!!';
    }));

    return $twig;
}));
```

Reference: http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html#customization

Comment: Works perfectly in Slim framework. But replace the class name, according to: "As of Twig 2.x, the Twig_SimpleFilter class is deprecated and will be removed in Twig 3.x (use \Twig\TwigFilter instead). In Twig 2.x, Twig_SimpleFilter is just an alias for \Twig\TwigFilter."

Answer (score 0):

For the record, the new way to register a Twig extension now is as following :

```
$app['twig'] = $app->extend('twig', function (\Twig_Environment $twig, Silex\Application $app) {
    $twig->addExtension(new My_Twig_Extension($app));

    return $twig;
});
```

The documentation http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/twig.html#customization has been updated.

tim